# Accessing and populating another class's properties in DAL BLL setup

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I'd like to return in `BLLServiceRequests` the `DALServiceRequest` properties along with its corresponding `DALRequest` properties since the SP I used is a JOIN table between `Request` and `ServiceRequest` tables. The problem is when I hit this code:

> var requestNewProjects =
>   Common.ToList(dt);

It can't find the `DALRequest` properties I've set in `DALServiceRequest`'s properties. Could someone point out to me the correct way to implement this? Thank you.

BLL

```
public class BLLServiceRequests
{

    public List<DALServiceRequests.Properties> GetServiceRequestByRequestId(intrequestID)
    {
        var obj = new DALServiceRequests();
        return obj.GetServiceRequestByRequestId(requestID);
    }
}
```

DAL

```
public class DALRequests
{
    public class Properties
    {
        public int id {get;set;}
        public int requestType { get; set; }
        public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
    }
}

public class DALServiceRequests
{
    public class Properties
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int requestId { get; set; }
        public string Issue { get; set; }
        public DALRequests.Properties request { get; set; } //Is this correct?
    }

    public List<DALServiceRequests.Properties> GetServiceRequestByRequestId(int requestID)
    {
        string cnStr = Common.dbConnStr;

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "GetServiceRequestByRequestId";
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@requestID", requestID);

        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cn;
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            var requestNewProjects = Common.ToList<DALServiceRequests.Properties>(dt);
            //Code above can't find the DALRequests properties which is already defined in DALServiceRequests.Properties

            return requestNewProjects;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            cn.Close();
            cn.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            dt.Dispose();
            adapter.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my Common class in DAL. Nothing to see here it's just a utility class I use to convert datatable to list

```
public static class Common
{
    public static string dbConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnString"].ToString();

    public static List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable table)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        T item;
        Type listItemType = typeof(T);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            item = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(listItemType);
            MapRow(item, table, listItemType, i);
            list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static void MapRow(object vOb, DataTable table, Type type, int row)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < table.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            var columnName = table.Columns[col].ColumnName;
            var prop = type.GetProperty(columnName);
            object data = table.Rows[row][col];

            if (data == System.DBNull.Value)
            {
            }
            else
                prop.SetValue(vOb, data, null);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance).

```
public class DALServiceRequests:DALRequests
```

If you add `DALRequests` to `DALServiceRequests` it will give you acces to all the properties inside `DALRequests` including all methods but as i see you only have properties in `DALRequests`

And a other way would be to just define the class as a property as you did before but without the `.properties`

```
public DALRequests request { get; set; }
```

Then you can acces the properties in the following way:

```
DALServiceRequests req = new DALServiceRequests(); 
var somePropInfo = req.DALRequests.createDate;// Fill it correcly in line above
```